# n2n VPN - lots of network traffic on supernode

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, p2p

I built a P2P VPN between:

1. Raspberry Pi running Jessie (attached to an LTE dongle) and
2. Ubuntu 16.04 desktop (with independent network connection)

How I did it: I purchased a cheap VPS (to init the P2P connection), apt-get installed [n2n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N2n) on all three machines, and set up virtual network as follows:

VPS ('supernode' in the n2n language):

```
$> supernode -l 5000
```

Desktop:

```
$> sudo edge -d edge0 -a 10.0.0.11 -c mynetwork -u 1000 -g 1000 -k password -l <VPS_IP_ADDR>:5000 -m ae:e0:4f:xx:yy:zz
```

Raspberry Pi:

```
$> sudo edge -d edge0 -a 10.0.0.10 -c mynetwork -u 1000 -g 1000 -k password -l <VPS_IP_ADDR>:5000 -m ae:e0:4f:xx:yy:zz
```

So far it worked like a charm. I played movies through RTSP, SSHed way and back, copied files, netcat'ed dirty things, and many more. But I started to worry when I ran bandwidth monitor ([bmon](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bmon)) on VPS. What turned out is that **VPS (supernode) has lots of traffic on its network iface.** By 'lots' I mean 'as much as the peers have'. This is not what I would expect from a P2P connection.

**My questions therefore are:**

1. Do I use n2n correctly?
2. How to prevent n2n from wasting VPS bandwidth in my setup?
3. How to tell that I have a **real** P2P connection?
4. Any other tools out there? I need it to be P2P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from developer of n2n, so I'm posting it here.

What I observe is a consequence of nodes not being able to establish P2P connection. This is because reverse UDP tunnelling is blocked at some stage.
In such case traffic falls back to a path involving supernode.

As for the alternatives, this is what I found (untested):

- [wippien](http://www.wippien.com/)
- [IPOP](http://ipop-project.org/)